# Why is $1+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+...+\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=2-\frac{1}{n}$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Why is this equality true? $$1+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+...+\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=2-\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Observe $\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n$

Comment: LHS is infact equal to RHS so the inequality is not true.

Comment: So it would be correct to ask *why is this false?*

Comment: @ShubhamJohri sry, I pasted it from an analysis workbook

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As some people have already commented, the inequality isn't true, because the left hand side is exactly equal to the right hand side. Note that the sum on the left-hand side is simply a telescoping sum; with the observation that $1/(n(n-1)) = 1/(n-1) - 1/n$, we have $$1 + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n (n-1)} = 1 + \bigg(\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k - 1} - \frac{1}{k} \bigg) =   1 + \bigg( 1 - \frac 1n \bigg) = 2 - \frac 1n.$$ Note that the second equality holds because the middle terms all cancel out (i.e. it's a telescoping sum), leaving only the first half of the first term and the second half of the last term.

Answer (score 4):

${1\over n(n-1)}={n-(n-1)\over n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac 1n$

Thus your expression simplifies to:
$1+(1-\frac 12)+(\frac 12-\frac 13)+...+(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac 1n)=2-\frac 1n$

Answer (score 1):

Generally
$$\frac{1}{n(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k}\left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+k}\right)$$
So we can calculate the exact value of left hand side as other solutions above.